# JS Accessing variable outside the founction

Tags: javascript

I've tried different methods..
I need to access url outside the function

```
var url = '';

chrome.tabs.getSelected(1, function(tab){
    url = tab.url;
});

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Your example would work. What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Actually, unless that function is executed asychronously, in which case, it won't.

Comment: Note that this API is deprecated: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected .